# How to force span's background color to be 100% width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to force a span element background to be the full width of parent.


**Heads Up**
Yes… I'm fully aware of doing divs…

> (but divs are more of a hack rather than an actual solution to the problem)

Must be something similar to a span or span… due to its text fluidity.
Must be in a `pre` tag.

## Structure Setup Must be

`<div>`
`<pre>`
`text text text` `<span>` `text text`
`text text` `</span>`
`</pre>`
`</div>`

## What I have

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(54, 188, 255, 0.05);
  color: #515D6F;
}

.one {
  background: rgba(54, 188, 255, 0.15);
  color: rgba(54, 188, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <pre>
 
Here is something<span class="one"> hello 

there
      how are you
      are you
      are you
      are you</span>
    
Here is something else

</pre>
</div>
```

## What I'm trying to achieve

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(54, 188, 255, 0.05);
  color: #515D6F;
}

.one {
  background: rgba(54, 188, 255, 0.15);
  color: rgba(54, 188, 255, 1);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 133px);
}

.left {
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
}

.demo {
  color: rgba(54, 188, 255, 1);
  background: rgba(54, 188, 255, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <pre>

<div class="left">Here is something</div><div class="one right"> hello</div>
<div class="demo">
there
      how are you
      are you
      are you
      are you</div>
Here is something else
  </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution I could come up with is the following:

```css
div {
  display: table;      /* without these 2 lines, iOS Safari ignores */
  table-layout: fixed; /* the width setting... maybe a bug?         */
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(54, 188, 255, 0.05);
  color: #515D6F;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one {
  background: rgba(54, 188, 255, 0.15);
  color: rgba(54, 188, 255, 1);
  padding-right: 100vw;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <pre>
 
Here is something<span class="one"> hello 

there
      how are you
      are you
      are you
      are you</span>
    
Here is something else

</pre>
</div>
```

Known drawback: this solution hardly relies on text fitting in the container width, since it basically gets a constant amount of painted area at the right of each line that than gets cut to the container edge. If it is not acceptable, there is another approach based on using shadows:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(54, 188, 255, 0.05);
  color: #515D6F;
  overflow: auto;
}

.one {
  background: #d8f2ff;
  box-shadow: 20px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              40px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              60px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              80px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              100px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              120px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              140px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              160px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              180px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              200px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              220px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              240px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              260px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              280px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              300px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              320px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              340px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              360px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              380px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              400px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              420px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              440px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              460px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              480px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              500px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              520px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              540px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              560px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              580px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              600px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              620px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              640px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              660px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              680px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              700px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              720px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              740px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              760px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              780px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              800px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              820px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              840px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              860px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              880px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              900px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              920px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff,
              940px 0 0 0 #d8f2ff;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: rgba(54, 188, 255, 1);
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <pre>
 
Here is something<span class="one"> hello 

there
      how are you
      are you
      are you
      are you</span>
    
Here is something else with the very very very looooooooooooooooooooooong line of text, some really long line of text, really long

</pre>
</div>
```

Hovewer, it has another drawback: it can work only with solid color, because parts of the shadow overlap and overlapping of semi-transparent shadows looks ugly.

Comment: There is one small bug I just found… The text is cut off when I use this on a long paragraph

Comment: How do I fix this

Comment: The problem lie with the overflow hidden

Comment: Yes, this was the known drawback of my approach(. I updated the answer with the different solution (although not ideal, too).

Answer (score 2):

Try add this in span tag or span class

```
.one {
background: rgba(54, 188, 255, 0.15);
color: rgba(54, 188, 255, 1);
width: 100%;
display: block;
```

}

You have to use **display:block and width:100;** in the span tag.

Comment: This comes really close… but it forces it to be like a div

Comment: It's in a block… I was hoping to keep all text in it's current placement

Comment: I guess I'm looking for something like a wrap